# How to set the <%= ...> in to a loop counter?

Tags: java, jsp

I want to ask a question about the JSP. I writing the following code in the JSP page. However, when I set the `<%= obj.getCounter()%>` (use-defined method) to be the loop counter, I found that it does not work. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

The following is the code.

```
<%
private int loopTime = <%= obj.getCounter()%>;
%>

<% for(int i=0; i<loopTime; i++) { %>
<tr>
    <td><%= obj.getName() %></td>
    <td><%= obj.getAge() %></td>
</tr>
<%}%>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't include one scriptlet inside another: what's the point?

```
<% int loopTime = obj.getCounter(); %>
```

Is this what you wanted? I'm asking because `loopTime` isn't the 'loop counter' in your code, it's loop upper boundary.